# BIOS time is incorrect

Tags: 12.10, bios, time, clock

OK here's a weird question.

I have like, 7 year old hardware. I have Ubuntu 12.10 installed. If I ever have a need to go into the BIOS, it's showing the time incorrect - I think it's showing it in GMT. I'm in EST. When I go into Ubuntu, it reflects the time accurately in the OS.

If I correct the time in the BIOS and go into Ubuntu then reboot into BIOS again, the time is once again set to GMT.

Is this normal behavior?

Comment: Your system time should be in UTC. Here's some light reading: http://yellerapp.com/posts/2015-01-12-the-worst-server-setup-you-can-make.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is normal to have the BIOS time in UTC.